# PyInstaller: Support cmd and Gui mode?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyinstaller

Is there a way to make my PyInstalled Pythoncode run either in CMD or in GUI mode?

My intention is: If the user drops a file to my .exe file, I want to immediately start processing it (and therefore show the results within the CMD window as usual), if the user does not drop a file, I want to show a Gui, ask a few option and only after pressing the "start"-button, I want to start analyzing and show the results within a textfield in the gui.

The problem for me seems, which I found here on SO: *"showing console seems to be the default behaviour. you may change this via -w, --windowed, --noconsole"*

So is it imopssible to decide upon runtime whether to show the GUI or to show the console?

Thanks!